# Creating a vertical parallax page

Tags: jquery, html, parallax

I'm trying to create a vertical scrolling web page similar to http://editions.redbullusa.com with jquery. I came across the script below, I am able to fade in the elements correctly as I scroll down the page, however I would like to have the previous element fade out when the next element is being scrolled into position and when scrolling back up fade in the correct elements, in essence reverse the script.

```
    slides = $('.slide');
slides.children().fadeTo(0, 0);
$('#slide-1').children().fadeTo(1000, 1);
$(window).scroll(function(d,h) {
    slides.each(function(i) {
        a = $(this).position().top + $(this).height();
        b = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
        if (a < b) { 
            $(this).addClass('current');
            $(this).children().fadeTo(1000,1);
            $(this).children('.polaroid').addClass('fadeInRightBig');
            $(this).siblings().removeClass('current');
        }
    });
});
```

I'm really at a loss as to how to make this happen. I'm hoping someone can help me out here. The site I'm toying with is http://interesponse.com/curryacura/index2.php

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a parallax plugin, try stellar js, just add data-attributes to your elements and stellar will take care of the animation.

http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/